# Build a binary tree from a Python list

Tags: python, binary-tree

Let's say I have the following binary tree:

[image]

and the following `TreeNode` definition:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x, left: = None, right: = None):
        self.val = x
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

To construct this tree, I currently need to write the following code:

```
def build_tree() -> TreeNode:
    node0 = TreeNode(2, left=TreeNode(4), right=TreeNode(5))
    node1 = TreeNode(3, right=TreeNode(7))
    root = TreeNode(1, left=node0, right=node1)
    return root
```

This is very inefficient for large trees. Leetcode gives me trees as a Python list. For the example above, it reads:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None, 7]
```

I would love to refactor `build_tree` so it takes a list, builds the tree and returns the root node:

```
def build_tree(values: list) -> ListNode:
    ...
```

Any ideas on how to create this function?

Here's a more complicated example:

```
[4, 6, 2, None, 5, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, None, 7]
```

[image]

Comment: this may help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq#theory

Comment: Any feedback on the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

assuming your list is already in the order described by https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq#theory you could do this (if it is not, use [`heapq.heapify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify)):

```
def from_list(elements):
    root_node = TreeNode(x=elements[0])
    nodes = [root_node]
    for i, x in enumerate(elements[1:]):
        if x is None:
            continue
        parent_node = nodes[i // 2]
        is_left = (i % 2 == 0)
        node = TreeNode(x=x)
        if is_left:
            parent_node.left = node
        else:
            parent_node.right = node
        nodes.append(node)

    return root_node
```

i store all the nodes in a list called `nodes`. iterating over the `elements` i then know how to find the parent node in the `nodes` list.

using the recursive print function

```
def print_recursive(tree, level=0, prefix="root"):
    print(f"{level * '  '}{prefix:5s}: val={tree.val}")
    if tree.left:
        print_recursive(tree.left, level + 1, "left")
    if tree.right:
        print_recursive(tree.right, level + 1, "right")
```

and running it for your second example

```
tree = from_list(elements=[4, 6, 2, None, 5, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, None, 7])
print_recursive(tree)
```

i get:

```
root : val=4
  left : val=6
    right: val=5
      left : val=2
      right: val=1
  right: val=2
    left : val=1
      left : val=3
      right: val=4
    right: val=9
      right: val=7
```

Comment: Does ```heapq.heapify``` generate ```None``` values in the example input lists?

Comment: @mherzog no, `heapify` will re-order your list in-place and add no new elements.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function when solving LeetCode problems. It has these characteristics:

- It really uses LeetCode's input format, so it does not follow the heap-organisation, but skips entries when the corresponding parent is already `None` -- contrary to what the heap-format would do.
- It uses a queue so to insert nodes in the correct (breadth-first) order
- It uses an iterator over the input list

Code:

```
def to_binary_tree(items):
    if not items:
        return None

    it = iter(items)
    root = TreeNode(next(it))
    q = [root]
    for node in q:
        val = next(it, None)
        if val is not None:
            node.left = TreeNode(val)
            q.append(node.left)
        val = next(it, None)
        if val is not None:
            node.right = TreeNode(val)
            q.append(node.right)
    return root
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the code like this. It will take a list of numbers or string and will build a BST but for simple binary tree, only one `if` condition will needs to be removed.

```
def add_child(self, val):
    if val == self.val:
        return
    
    elif val < self.val:
        if self.left:
            self.left.add_child(val)
        else:
            self.left = BinarySearchTree(val)
    else:
        if self.right:
            self.right.add_child(val)
        else:
            self.right = BinarySearchTree(val)

def build_tree(elements):
     root = BinarySearchTree(elements[0])
     for i in range(1, len(elements)):
         root.add_child(elements[i])

     return root

if __name__=="__main__":
     numbers = [15, 10, 8, 12, 20, 16, 25]        
     root = build_tree(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your elements and convert the list to a tree this way. This isn't very memory efficient (it will store a pointer to each node on the queue so you're looking at O(N) in terms of data) but it will be more efficient in terms of CPU, especially in Python.

```
def build_tree(data):

    # Check if we have data; if we don't then return None
    if not data:
        return None

    # Create our tree object from the root and then
    # add it to a list of nodes that we can add data to
    tree = TreeNode(data[0])
    queue = [data[0]]    

    # Iterate over the rest of the nodes and add
    # them to the tree
    index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(data) - 1):

        # If our node is None then we have a leaf so
        # there's no work to do; otherwise, create the
        # node and add it to the proper spot
        if data[i] != None:

            # Create the node from the data
            node = TreeNode(data[i])

            # If the index we're looking at is even
            # then we have a left branch; otherwise we
            # have a right branch so add the node to the
            # appropriate side of the tree
            if i % 2 == 0:
                queue[index].left = node
            else:
                queue[index].right = node)

            # Add the node to our queue so it can
            # be referenced later
            queue.append(node)

        # Finally, update our index if we've finished looking
        # at this node. As each branch may only have two children
        # we only need to do this if we're looking at odd-indexed
        # entries because leaves will always be None (unless we've
        # reached the last level of the tree)
        index += i % 2

    return tree
```

This algorithm works by building a queue from the data (which already had a heap structure anyway) while creating the nodes. Because the queue is iterated only when the current node is full and because it iterates left-to-right, the order of the tree will be preserved.